# Laravel's Eloquent Group By / Count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've a simple dashboard page with a few Eloquent queries with similar setup as follows:

```
Activity::where('name','school')
->groupBy('values->name')
->whereBetween('created_at', [$period['start'], $period['end']])
->orderBy('views','desc')
->get(array(
    'values->name as name',
    DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
));
```

Essentially I just need group results and count the total of each (it is a JSON column).

The database have a little over 1m entries and just this query alone takes like 3-4 seconds. I'm no expert with SQL so I'm wondering if there any better solution to make this type of job more efficient or is due MariaDB / Laravel?

Here's the result of explain()

```
"id": 1,
"select_type": "SIMPLE",
"table": "activities",
"partitions": null,
"type": "ALL",
"possible_keys": null,
"key": null,
"key_len": null,
"ref": null,
"rows": 1496271,
"filtered": 1.1110000610351562,
"Extra": "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

Comment: I see you are grouping by a json column. That might cause a lot of overhead. The last time I used MariaDB, I think it didn't even have support for json columns. Everything "json" was stored as longtext in the dabatase which wasn't ideal either. Try replacing `get(....)` by  `select(...)` and then appending `->explain()`. Copy the results of this query here so we might see what the database is doing.

Comment: Added the result of ->explain() on the original post. I've tried simply use groupBy('values') instead of groupBy('values->name') and didn't notice much difference

Comment: You could try creating an index on the `name` column or a composite index on  `(name, created_at)` and check if that changes your performance. Instead of using the model (`Activity`), you could use the query builder (`DB::table('activities')`). It might affect the performance.